# Why does it show me a sum of 0?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I just wrote a discord bot and used a function to show me the members of each guild the bot is in. That worked all the time but now i wanted to use a other server so i copied my files and dragged them on the other server. But for some reason now it says the sum of all the member = 0. Can someone help me?

Thx in advance ^^

```
async def member():
    while True:
        for guild in my_guild_id: # list of guild id's
            guild = bot.get_guild(guild)
            member = sum(discord.member and not member.bot for member in guild.members)
            for channel in members_channel_id: # list of channel id's
                check = str(guild.get_channel(channel)).encode('ascii', 'ignore') 
                if check != none:               # none = b'None' cause there were some bugs
                    channel = bot.get_channel(channel)
                    await channel.edit(name=f"Servermember: {Member}")
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function has the same name as a variable in the function, you should be using a different name for it.

Also, `none` takes a capitalized N: `None`.

Finally, you're using the variable `Member` when editing the channel, but this variable isn't defined, python is case-sensitive.

I don't think you just "copied and dragged" your files, and that couldn't work on another server...

Comment: so i really just copied it from my first to the second server and then it didnt work the way i inted. But then i tried to fix it myself and forgot to reedit it :P
`none` is a variable for `b'None'` cause its a different None that `None`if u get what im trying to say.

Comment: ok i changed the function name and the last variable so its fixed now. still the same prob

Comment: i did a test with a file and test outputs
and the one is with the right number for each server. the other output works, but not with the correct number. it says `0`
maybe there is a bug with the python version?